# disjunction-elimination subproof boxes LaTeX

Tags: boxes, logic, logicproof

How can I write subproofs side-by-side inside a logicproof environment in LaTeX like the one provided in the picture?
This type of proof is used when using disjunction-elimination laws in propositional logic.
[image]

**Edited**: To prove a disjunction, one needs to take the following steps:
[image]

meaning to get `$\chi$` from `$\phi \lor \psi$`, you need to find proof that `$\phi$` gives `$\chi$` and `$\psi$` gives `$\chi$` as well. and since this is done simultaneously, we use two subproof boxes next to each other.

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: Can you post code for the document you have? Could you also specify the system which uses proofs like this? (For example, which textbook?) I've not seen this format before and it's easier to find stuff with the name. There are several packages for boxed subproofs, though.

Comment: The best resource for logic is https://www.logicmatters.net/latex-for-logicians/ but, as I say, I'm not sure if there is anything quite like this out-of-the-box.

Comment: @cfr This notation is used in "Logic in Computer Science by Michael Huth & Mark Ryan", Chapter 1, Natural Deduction (Section 2), Example 1.20. I'm not sure whether this notation is widely used in other textbooks. This notation is mainly used when we want to use disjunction-elimination law and need to prove both atoms on either side of the disjunction.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani Ah, thanks. Disjunction elimination is a standard rule of inference in ND systems, but presented sequentially in the systems I'm familiar with. It would be a lot easier if every textbook didn't feel a need to develop its own notation. It means packages are only good for one or a very small number of ND proof systems.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani I looked at the book. The early examples actually present the sub-proofs sequentially rather than side-by-side. After example 1.20, they say either is acceptable. Is the sequential format an option for you? That format is a pretty standard one, so you could use a package which would support it more-or-less out-of-the-box. E.g. Peter Smith lists packages which support basically this style.

Comment: @cfr Thank you I'll make sure to check that out. My course teacher uses the notation I provided in the picture so I'm kinda desperate to use this exact style in my solutions to problem sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with `{NiceArray}` of `nicematrix` (and TikZ).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix,tikz}

\begin{document}

\[\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{10pt}
\begin{NiceArray}{lllll@{\enskip}}
1 & \neg p \lor q & \text{premise} \\
2 & \Block[tikz={draw,offset=1pt}]{5-2}{}
    \neg p  & \text{premise}      & \Block[tikz={draw,offset=1pt}]{5-2}{}
                                    q       & \text{premise} \\
3 & \Block[tikz={draw,offset=3pt}]{3-2}{}
    p       & \text{assumption}   & \Block[tikz={draw,offset=3pt}]{2-2}{}
                                    p       & \text{assumption} \\
4 & \bot    & \neg\text{e}\; 3,2  & q       & \text{copy } 2 \\
5 & q       & \bot\text{e}\; 4    & p \to q & \mathord{\to}\text{i} \; 3-4 \\
6 & p \to q & \mathord{\to}\text{i}\; 3-5 \\
7 & p \to q &                     &         & \lor\text{e}\; 1,2-6
\end{NiceArray}\]

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: I'm absolutely thankful for your and @cfr 's efforts in designing these custom environments. I believe the latter will suit my needs better in writing proof to a disjunctive operator.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani This is what I meant by correct alignment. But note that line 2 isn't a premise. It's an assumption. (Or, rather, they're assumptions.)

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend trying to use this in addition to learning logic. I assume you're allowed to hand write these and encourage you to do so.

Consider this proof-of-concept rather than a solution. There are at least two problems.

1. The alignment is visibly wrong when subproofs are used. That is, the wffs and justifications are not properly aligned with the corresponding line numbers inside subproofs. The content of the lines in the subproofs drift down relative to the corresponding line numbers (or the line numbers drift up relative to the content of the lines).
2. The syntax is frankly vile.

I suspect (1) can be resolved using the features provided by `tabularray`. I'm not at all familiar with this package --- I don't think I've used it before; if I have, it was for a single answer on SE or something like that --- and its documentation has no index and I can't quite get to grips with how, whether or where it specifies the syntax of commands.

(2) would require a proper approach with a custom interface, of the kind provided by various packages for natural deduction proofs. If this way of setting out proofs takes off, probably somebody will write one. (I tried to see if the books online resources provided anything, but I can't even find the page.)

### *Caveat emptor*

---

[image: side-by-side subproofs]

```
\documentclass{article}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702389/
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand*{\lfalse}{\ensuremath{\mathord{\bot}}}
\newcommand*{\lif}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\rightarrow}}}
\newcommand*{\liff}{\ensuremath{\mathbin{\leftrightarrow}}}
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \lcsno {} {\arabic{rownum}.}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={Q[l]Q[l,mode=math]Q[l]Q[l,mode=math]Q[l]},
  }
  \lcsno & \lnot p \lor q & premise &  &  \\
  \lcsno & \SetCell[r=5,c=2]{l}{%
    \begin{tblr}{baseline=T,colspec={|Q[l,mode=math]Q[l,mode=text]|}}
      \hline
      \lnot p & assumption \\
      \SetCell[r=3,c=2]{l}{%
        \begin{tblr}{baseline=T,colspec={|Q[l,mode=math]Q[l,mode=text]|}}
          \hline
          p & assumption \\
          \lfalse & excl.~middle 2,3 \\
          q & $\lnot$\,e 4   \\
          \hline
        \end{tblr}%
      } & \\
      & \\
      & \\
      p \lif q & \lif\, i 3--5 \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}%
  } & & \SetCell[r=5,c=2]{l}{%
    \begin{tblr}{baseline=T,colspec={|Q[l,mode=math]Q[l,mode=text]|}}
      \hline
      q & assumption \\
      \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{l}{%
        \begin{tblr}{baseline=T,colspec={|Q[l,mode=math]Q[l,mode=text]|}}
          \hline
          p & assumption \\
          q & repeat 2 \\
          \hline
        \end{tblr}%
      } & \\
      & \\
      p \lif q & \lif\, i 3--4  \\
      & \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}%
  } & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno & p \lif q & $\lor$\,e 1--6 & & \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

If you find subproofs disappear, note that `tabularray` is extremely picky and often just ignores stuff rather than warning you. Every cell replaced by a `\SetCell` must be explicitly created as an empty cell. It isn't enough to just leave space. For example, we couldn't replace

```
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
  \lcsno &  & &  & \\
```

with

```
  \lcsno  \\
  \lcsno  \\
  \lcsno  \\
  \lcsno  \\
```

or our subproofs would disappear. Unlike `\multicolumn`, `\SetCell` sometimes picks up the context from the first column it replaces. So the explicit `mode=text` is required in the subproofs or the justifications are typeset as maths.

Comment: Of course I'm allowed to hand-write the solutions. The point here is for me to have a robust template for writing my problem sets so I'm forcing myself to write everything in LaTeX and since my textbook uses this notation, I want to do so as well. IMO the alignment seems to be correct. I've edited my question to provide further information on why I think the alignment is correct. My preference is to stick to the `logicproof` package, even if there's no such implementation for this type of notation. I'll just use normal `subproof` enviroments

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani (1) When I said the alignment was wrong, I didn't mean putting the subproofs side-by-side. I meant that the alignment of the line numbers with the wffs and justifications is wrong in my answer. In a subproof, the line numbers are higher than the wffs and justifications on the same line. They should be aligned. For example `2.` is higher than `\lnot p`, `assumption`, `q` and `assumption`. All 5 of these things should line up properly, but only 4 of them do. The line numbers are all 'off'.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani (2) You may, of course, choose to do this in LaTeX. If you have the time and inclination to do so, there is no reason at all not to. It's just that sometimes the presentation can become a distraction from the content. But perhaps that's just me and it doesn't happen to you. (3) I'm not sure what you mean about using normal `subproof` environments. `logicproof` cannot put those side-by-side, can it?

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani I wonder if coffins would work better, but, if you really want to stick to `logicproof`, then I will let it be.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani I looked at `logicproof`'s code and you'd need to adapt it to build the more complex `tabular` column specification for `subproof`s. Theoretically, you could then pass `logicproof` the value of (number of linear subproofs) + 2(number of branching subproofs). This would hopefully feed `{{r@{~~~}*{#1}{l}@{~}>{$}l<{$}@{~~~~}l@{~}*{#1}{r}}}` the correct `#1`.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't find information about whether `logicproof` can put `subproof` environments side-by-side. The only thing I know is that I can pass the number of nested `subproof` environments to it. I'm not at all familiar with the code you provided `{{r@{~~~}*{#1}{l}@{~}>{$}l<{$}@{~~~~}l@{~}*{#1}{r}}}`.

Comment: @MahdiSoleimani That's the `tabular` column specification `logicproof` uses. `#1` is the number of nested subproofs which determines the number of columns. There's no provision here for side-by-side subproofs. You'd have to modify the macros used to create a subproof. (And I don't know if it would work.) Or you could maybe define a new macro for double-subproofs if you could get it to feed into that column spec in the same way `subproof` does.