# Aligning cells to baseline in nested tabularray

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, alignment, tabularray, baseline

How can I align cells by their baselines if `tabularray` `tblr` environments are nested?

I've seen several answers recommending `tabularray` and thought I'd try it out, but the package does several things which seem odd to me.

The following MWE actually exhibits the issue. The motivation for asking is [my attempted answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/702389/). I'd like to know if this is worth pursuing or whether a non-`tabularray` approach would be better.

[image: non-aligned baselines of cells in rows in nested tblrs]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\NewColumnType{K}{Q[l,h]Q[l,h]}
\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{%
    colspec={lK},
  }
  a & b & c \\
  a & \SetCell[r=3,c=2]{l}{%
    \begin{tblr}{%
        baseline=T,
        colspec={|K|},
      }
      \hline
      b & c\\ 
      \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{l}{%
        \begin{tblr}{%
            baseline=T,
            colspec={|K|},
          }
          \hline
          b & c\\ 
          b & c\\
          \hline
        \end{tblr}%
      } & \\
      &  \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}%
  } & \\
  a &   &   \\
  a &   &   \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

The only question I found on this topic had an answer which involved using `tabular` rather than `tabularray`. I can't find that right now, but I'll add the link if I manage to track it down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too tricky to be useful.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lll},
    hline{2}={2-Z}{},
    hline{3}={2-Z}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
    hline{Y}={1}{2-Z}{leftpos=0, rightpos=0},
    hline{Y}={2}{2-Z}{},
    vline{2}={1}{2-Y}{belowpos=1},
    vline{2}={2}{3-Y}{abovepos=1},
    vline{Z}={1}{3-Y}{abovepos=1},
    vline{Z}={2}{2-Y}{belowpos=1},
  }
  1 & b & c \\
  2 & b & c \\
  3 & b & c \\
  4 & b & c \\
  5 & b & c \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Since `tabularray` typesets each of its cells multiple times, nested `tabularray` tables become slow very quickly.

Comment: Wow. I had no idea it would be that complicated. I just assumed I was missing something somewhere. This basically answers my underlying question: this isn't a good approach to the problem. Aside from speed considerations, the configuration is just going to get absurdly complicated. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs} % For better horizontal lines

\NewColumnType{K}{Q[l,h]Q[l,h]}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec={lK},
  }
  a & b & c \\
  a & \SetCell[r=3,c=2]{l}{%
    \begin{tblr}{%
        baseline=T,
        colspec={|K|},
        abovesep=0pt,
        belowsep=0pt,
      }
      \hline
      b & c\\ 
      \SetCell[r=2,c=2]{l}{%
        \begin{tblr}{%
            baseline=T,
            colspec={|K|},
            abovesep=0pt,
            belowsep=0pt,
          }
          \hline
          b & c\\ 
          b & c\\
          \hline
        \end{tblr}%
      } & \\
      &  \\
      \hline
    \end{tblr}%
  } & \\
  a &   &   \\
  a &   &   \\
  a & b & c \\
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

I've set `abovesep` and `belowsep` to `0pt` in the nested `tblr` environments to reduce additional spacing that might affect the alignment.
Output:
[image: Table]

Comment: Thanks, but I need the letters in a row aligned at their baselines. Also, I need the space between the bottom parts of the boxes' frames. And `booktabs` isn't appropriate in this case because I need vertical rules. (Actually, your code doesn't use the `booktabs` stuff you load anyway - the package doesn't affect `\hline`.)